# Is it possible to restrict the functionality of JRuby?

Tags: ruby, jruby

Suppose that I have a Java program that uses JRuby to allow the user to use Ruby scripting to control the behaviour of some funny character in a window.

Users can share their Ruby code with the community, so others can execute the snippets on their own copy of the program and see the funny character do stuff.

I have a security concern with this, though, as users may contribute malicious Ruby code to the community.

The obvious precaution is that users shouldn't run the snippets of untrusted users. However, due to the nature of the community, the point ***is*** to check out the creations of strangers.

So, it has occurred to me that maybe I can restrict the capabilities of JRuby.

There may be other things, but some of the restrictions off of my head would be:

- Do not allow any sort of networking.
- No access to the filesystem.
- Do not permit system DOS calls.
- Can't require/import ruby code/gems/etc.
- Can't create new processes etc.

Is there a reasonable way to restrict JRuby functionality?

I have thought of, perhaps, redefining several constants that are required for that sort of operations. For instance,

```
File = nil
```

But I am unsure of what constants to nullify exactly, and whether this is effective at all.

Answer (score 0):

since your requirements are concrete you would likely need to implement those restrictions yourself ... some pointers :

- rubygems can be disable within JRuby - assuming it's fine for you to boot that way, otherwise chaing `load/require` is a good option
- same for `system` and similar calls that create a new process
- instead of doing `File = nil` early on you might end up needing to review File/IO methods one by one
- undefine `Java` constant and `java` methods to disallow smart cheating with Java APIs